# Command-line assistance like perldoc or python "help"?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, documentation

If I want command-line assistance in Perl I can use `perldoc`, for example let's assume I forgot that name of the function to calculate the length of an array, I could use

```
perldoc perldata
```

Or even `perldoc -f length` if I remember it..

Likewise in Python I could do,

```
a = []
help(a)
```

Is there a method in Rust to get a quick doc page that doesn't require a browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cargo you could use the `cargo doc --open` command to generate and open offline docs in the browser

If you're looking for a command line tool try [rustyman](https://crates.io/crates/rusty-man) or try looking in [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/command-line-tool-for-viewing-documentation/17145/5)

Comment: If you're looking for a command line tool try [rustyman](https://crates.io/crates/rusty-man) or try looking in [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/command-line-tool-for-viewing-documentation/17145/5)

Comment: if you want to repurpose this answer for rusty-man I'll accept it and even write much of it myself. That's exactly what I'm looking for.